# Want to add two floating buttons in a listview

Tags: android, google-plus, imagebutton, floating

I am developing an app in which i want to add two **floating buttons** like **google+**.

For that I am using [makovkastar/FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)

But actually it works for only one button if i add another button then the added button not work(it means the button is not gone when list view in scroll).

I had try following code but not works.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_floating_action1);

         FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_floating_action2);

            floatingActionButton1.attachToListView(getListView());
            floatingActionButton2.attachToListView(getListView());

            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets));
            getListView().setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could **open a dialog with 2 buttons** inside, by pressing your FAB.

Comment: @DerGolem:I am not getting what your are exactly suggesting me to do.If you have any solution or code plz let me knw

Comment: You can use a single FAB to open a Dialog. Then, in the Dialog, you can choose from 2 different buttons (or even more). I don't have code, just an idea on how to manage your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From looking in library code ,

```
    public void attachToListView(@NonNull AbsListView listView, ScrollDirectionListener listener) {
        AbsListViewScrollDetectorImpl scrollDetector = new AbsListViewScrollDetectorImpl();
        scrollDetector.setListener(listener);
        scrollDetector.setListView(listView);
        scrollDetector.setScrollThreshold(mScrollThreshold);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(scrollDetector);
    }
```

It seems it sets **setOnScrollListener** to listview which can have only one instance for single listview.

So it may not work until you **dig and play with library project**.

Another alternative is using **popup of floating action buttons** as in this App.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote.skitch

for bouncing effect of popup you can use great Rebound Lib from facebook.

http://facebook.github.io/rebound/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too,

```
  List<Widget> float_buttons() { 
  List button_list = List<Widget>();
  int i = 0;
  List names  = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth'];
  List P_type = [1,0,1,1,0];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    button_list.add(
      FloatingActionButton.extended(onPressed: (){}, label: Text(names[i]), icon: P_type[i]==1?Icon(Icons.star):Icon(Icons.panorama),)
    );
    button_list.add(
      SizedBox(width: 10,)
    );
  }
  return button_list;
}
```

And use this function within Expanded for better results

```
Expanded(child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            children: [Container(
              child: Row(
                children:  float_buttons(),
              ),
            )],
          ))
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWfRR.png)